# What do “truxtop” and “thumb tax” mean?

Tags: meaning, orthography, formality, colloquialisms

What do *tru**x**top* and *thumb ta**x*** mean?

I found them mentioned in this quotation from [*English Words History and Structure*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521709172), 2<sup>nd</sup> edition (p. 113):

> The replacement of the sequence [ks] by ***x*** is a spelling convention. It has no effect on the
>   pronunciation of the consonant cluster. This replacement practice has given rise to attention-getting facetious spellings like *thanx*, ***truxtop***, ***thumb tax***.

Comment: As your source has stated, replace the _x_ with the letters _ks_. This will give you _truckstop_ and _thumbtacks_.

Comment: _ks_ or _cks_ as appropriate.

Comment: ....  they used to have a head tax, but some bright guy discovered that if they changed to a thumb tax it would (nearly) double their take ....

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what *truxtop* is. But I've found a definition for *thumb tax*: 
[reference](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=thumbtack)

So *thumb tax* stands for *thumbtacks* (plural)